# Ajax Code work on localhost but not on server

Tags: php, ajax

I am working on 2 dependent dropdowns (Country, State). On the bases of previous selection, new drop-down options will open using ajax. My code works fine in localhost but on the server, it doesn't fetch any data(ajax not working on the server). I am using 2 files(Reg.php, getState.php) code is here, plz help.

**Reg.php**

```
<?php
require("../conn.php");
$query ="SELECT * FROM country";
$results=mysqli_query($con,$query);
?>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function getState(val) {
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "getState.php",
data:'country_id='+val,
success: function(data){
    $("#state-list").html(data);
    getCity();
}
});
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<select name="country" id="country-list" onChange="getState(this.value);">
<option value="">Select Country</option>
<?php 
foreach($results as $country) {
?>
<option value="<?php echo $country["id"]; ?>"><?php echo 
$country["country_name"]; ?></option>
<?php
}
?>
</select>
<select name="state" id="state-list"  class="form-control" style="width:100%;" onChange="getCity(this.value);">
<option value="">Select State</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

**getState.php**

```
<?php
require("../conn.php");
if (! empty($_POST["country_id"])) {
$query = "SELECT * FROM states WHERE countryID = '" . $_POST["country_id"] . "'";
$results=mysqli_query($con,$query);
?>
<option value disabled selected>Select State</option>
<?php
foreach ($results as $state) {
    ?>
<option value="<?php echo $state["id"]; ?>"><?php echo $state["name"]; ?> 
</option>
<?php
  }
 }
?>
```

Comment: You're sending ajax post request to **getState.php** and file name is **State.php**

Comment: file name is updated here

Comment: @Shalini :- Which type of error are you getting...It would be better if you will share the error here.

Comment: i doesn't get any error. But no value show in state dropdown

Comment: @Shalini Seems like database connection not established.

Comment: i checked for connection it works fine

Comment: @Shalini Have you privileged database user to access data ?

Comment: @Smartpal everything done correctly. i have one another query for inserting the data and it works.

Comment: @Shalini Alright

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the above code foreach loop working well on localhost but not on the server, I replace the foreach loop with while loop and get the country & city name. Thanks to everyone

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code for getting data from ajax.

```
function getState(val) {
        $.ajax({
          method: "POST",
          url: "getState.php",
          data: { country_id: val }
        })
          .done(function( data ) {
            $("#state-list").html(data);
          });
```

}

Comment: I think this foreach() code is not working on server. if i echo the country_name it show " "(blank).